# SFC components nuxt 3 structure

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I want to use nuxt system with one expection. I dont want to use one vue file with ts,less,and tempalte definition.

I want use vue file as main which imports the styles and ts logic.

like

```
<template>
  <div class="catalog">
   There is template code
  </div>
</template>
<script src="./catalog.js"></script>
<style lang="less" scoped src="./catalog.less"></style>
```

I have following nuxt config definition for that:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    components: [
        { path: "~/components/items", prefix: "items-" },
        "~/components",
    ],
});
```

But when i try to use 
i get following warn :

```
  Two component files resolving to the same name ItemsCatalog:                                                                                                        

 - C:/xampp/htdocs/project/spa2/frontend/components/items/catalog/catalog.vue
 - C:/xampp/htdocs/project/spa2/frontend/components/items/catalog/catalog.ts
```

And components doesnot render:

```
[Vue warn]: Component <Anonymous> is missing template or render function.                                                                                                   01:15:52
```

Is there is any ways to use components folder structure https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/components

But with following exclude :

Instead of

```
| components/
--| base/
----| foo/
------| Button.vue
```

Use the

```
| components/
    --| base/
    ----| foo/
    ------| button/button.vue
    ------| button/button.ts
    ------| button/button.less
```

Answer (score 0):

The Vue component file names should be Pascal case.

```
| components/
    --| base/
    ----| foo/
    ------| button/Button.vue
    ------| button/button.ts
    ------| button/button.less
```

And you use this button in the template:

```
<BaseFooButton />
```

Remove your components config in nuxt.config.ts and this approach will work.

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/components#component-names

Comment: Seems that still not working,event with _ before ts.

Comment: WARN  Two component files resolving to the same name ItemsCatalog:                                                                                01:41:36  

 - C:/xampp/htdocs/project/spa2/frontend/components/items/catalog/_catalog.ts
 - C:/xampp/htdocs/project/spa2/frontend/components/items/catalog/Catalog.vue